# Loop round folders to find and list which folders contain a file excluding a keyword, in bash?

Tags: find, file-search

I want to loop through thousands of folders all which contain a file called `output(foldernumber).txt` and check which of these output files DO NOT contain a keyword and have the script write out a list of these output files, so further analysis can be completed on them.

This is what I have so far:

```
a=1
b=1
for i in ~pwd ;do
(cd $i/ && grep -L 'keyword' output"$a".txt >> ../list.txt)
a=$((a+b))
done
```

Errors given say the output files do not exist and a blank `list.txt` file is made. Any advice please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -type f -regex ".*/output[0-9]*\.txt" -exec grep -L 'keyword' '{}' +
```

or

```
 find . -type f -regex ".*/output[0-9]*\.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -L 'keyword'
```

Comment: Thank you- both lines work in the script, however I have tested this on 100 folders and I am expecting to get 20 file names of output files that don't contain the keyword- but I am only getting back 4. Any help with what may be causing the script to miss out results?

Comment: You can verify the find results  if it contains the missing file at all: `find . -type f -regex ".*/output[0-9]*.txt" `

Comment: Should the literal dot be escaped (`\.txt`), since it's a regex match rather than a glob?